# How can I parse the information between two variables into a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am having difficulty parsing matrices contained between two variables. Here is an example of a matrix that I am attempting to extract into a numpy array:

```
</MO Number>
4.224609607748e+00  4.085857782359e+00  1.273383604708e+00 -6.802974691818e-03
9.099528133406e-03  6.867550219273e-03  5.859231188647e-03  3.684441849425e-03
5.836775773317e-04 -2.316776085880e-16 -1.456850991492e-16 -2.307897076406e-17
4.140895678156e-03  2.603906355541e-03  4.125025757803e-04 -1.739011495381e-03
-1.681896173898e-03 -5.241735641835e-04 -1.739011375813e-03 -1.681896058258e-03
-5.241735281434e-04
<MO Number>
```

Here is the code I have written:

```
def function3(start, end):
    lines = f.readlines()
    config_found = False
    var = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip() == end:
            config_found = False
        elif config_found:
            i = line.rstrip()
            var.append(i)
        elif line.strip() == start:
            config_found = True
    var1 = [elem.strip() for elem in var]
    var2 = var1[1:-1]
    return var2
 with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    mo1=np.array(function3(m['start1'],m['end1']))
```

where the start1 and end1 variables denote the headers. 
However, this returns the following:

```
   array([ '4.224609607748e+00  4.085857782359e+00  1.273383604708e+00 -6.802974691818e-03',
   '9.099528133406e-03  6.867550219273e-03  5.859231188647e-03  3.684441849425e-03',
   '5.836775773317e-04 -2.316776085880e-16 -1.456850991492e-16 -2.307897076406e-17',
   '4.140895678156e-03  2.603906355541e-03  4.125025757803e-04 -1.739011495381e-03',
   '-1.681896173898e-03 -5.241735641835e-04 -1.739011375813e-03 -1.681896058258e-03',
   '-5.241735281434e-04'])
```

It seems that my code stores each line of the matrix as a single element, when I would actually like it to store each floating point number as an individual element, separated by a comma. So, something like this:

```
 [ '4.224609607748e+00', '4.085857782359e+00', '1.273383604708e+00' '-6.802974691818e-03',
   '9.099528133406e-03', '6.867550219273e-03', '5.859231188647e-03' '3.684441849425e-03',
```

etc. 
Any help would be much appreciated on how I can modify my code, or even an entirely different approach to this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [split](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)() to divide a string into a list of strings by space.

`var2 = [line.split() for line in var2]`